# IntelliJ SBT Error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a SBT project that I'm trying to import into IntelliJ 14.1.3! I use Scala 2.10.3 and SBT 0.13.0 and IntelliJ uses the Scala plugin version 1.5.2. When I tried to import, I get the following error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Projects\myProj\project\target\scala-2.10\sbt-0.13\classes...
[error] error while loading <root>, error in opening zip file
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredPackage(Mirrors.scala:175)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:183)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage(Definitions.scala:183)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:184)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass(Definitions.scala:184)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1024)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr(Definitions.scala:1023)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1153)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1152)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1196)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1196)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1261)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1290)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:113)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:113)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:99)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:46)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:75)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:66)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:770)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:762)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:762)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:compile) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
```

Strangely, I was able to successfully import the very same project in my Mac!

Comment: What happens when you build in the terminal with sbt compile?

Comment: I get the same error when running the project using sbt run from a console

Comment: Add the `build.sbt` file to your post

Comment: It is a Play project and all I have is a Build.scala. I just noticed that the Build.scala has Scala version 2.11.5 and I have 2.10.3 installed on my machine. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Go for it, upgrade Scala (preferred) or downgrade your project

Comment: I'm just doing that! Let me post what happens after upgrading Scala! But what bemuses me is that the same configuration settings (scala 2.10.3) worked without any flaws on my Mac

Comment: That unfortunately did not work!

Comment: As a last try, I'm clearing out all my ivy cache!